# Read color values of an image in a particular order using Python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

For my program, I need to be able to convert an image into an array of color values. However I need to read the image in a particular order, bottom to top, left to right.
This means starting at the bottom left pixel, reading up to the top left, then move to the bottom of the second line and read upwards again.
As an example, the image below should be read as

> Black, Black, White, Black, Black, White, White, Black etc.

I'm only interested in whether the pixel is black or white. I know how to get this from RGB tuples, but if there is a way that  only reads the black/white value of the pixel, that would be great.

[image: 4x4 Example Image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Also, please post the array that represents your image

Comment: You haven't specified the input format -- it may not *have* a simple gray-scale value for you to read -- and you haven't shown your attempted code.  If you have no code yet, then you're not ready to post: how to read an image and access the values, is a topic covered in a variety of places on line.

Comment: @Prune Ok, I see I've made a mistake in posting this way to soon. Thanks for your time.